# Receive random unwanted message

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp8266

I am new to arduino and I have a problem with ESP8266. I want to check the echo from ESP8266 but when I upload the program and restart Nanoin COM4 serial window I am recieving some unwanted message . When I try to send AT commands I can see in NANo TX Led sends but ESP8266 is not responding. I changed all the baudrate, but only 115200 can able to readable.

I don't know if it is a hardware issue or should I have to update the firmware. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

void setup() 
{
  uint32_t baud = 115200;
  Serial.begin(baud);
  softSerial.begin(baud);
  Serial.print("SETUP!! @");
  Serial.println(baud);
}

void loop() 
{
    while(softSerial.available() > 0) 
    {
      char a = softSerial.read();
      if(a == '\0')
        continue;
      if(a != '\r' && a != '\n' && (a < 32))
        continue;
      Serial.print(a);
    }

    while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char a = Serial.read();
      Serial.write(a);
      softSerial.write(a);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: *I changed all the baudrate, but only 115200 can able to readable.* What command did you use to change the baudrate? Or did you try to change the baud rate by changing the firmware? If by AT command, what command did you use and what response did you receive?

Comment: First of all thanks for reply,I changed baudrate "  uint32_t baud = 115200;
" in program and Serial com to view... I can't make it firmware because I can't see the AT echos, Because When  I switched on I am getting above mentioned message continuesly .....

Comment: If you don't change the ESP8266's baud rate, then of course only its default baud rate will work.

Comment: How do i know the default baudrate of esp8266

Comment: Unless you installed unusual firmware, it's 115200.

Answer (score 0):

When the chip restarts, the bootloader prints out the boot debug log at `76800` baud. Then the application is loaded and it changes the serial to its specified baud rate (this is usually `115200`). The boot log will be seen as garbage at other baud-rates because UART signals do not have a clock.
If the bootloader fails because the firmware has not been flashed properly, it might get stuck in a bootloop which is likely what you are seeing.